# Getting formatted output in file using PrintStream (java 1.4)

Tags: file-io, formatting, java1.4

I have to write formatted output in the file in java 1.4 environment (for compatibility).
My object is PrintStream out; and I need to write something like: out.format("%-5s", data);
How Can I make that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized using out.format will also work, i will need to supply buffer arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You might try an [old implementation of printf](http://www.sharkysoft.com/archive/printf/download/) that's now redundant for the newer JVMs.

Comment: linking extra jar libraries was not something I was looking for. If nothing comes through I think that will be my option.

Comment: I realized using out.format will also work, i will need to supply buffer arguments.